# Postgresql function doesn't work properly

Tags: postgresql

Why is my function returning only half the zip codes?

I mean if i do

```
insert into address(zip_code) values(99-100)
```

it's doesn't work properly, because it's adding only "99-".

```
CREATE FUNCTION normalize_zip_code() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    if length(NEW.zip_code)<=4 and length(NEW.zip_code)>=6 then
         RAISE EXCEPTION 'Wrong zip code!';
    elsif length(NEW.zip_code)=6 and (SUBSTRing(NEW.zip_code, 3, 1)='-') then
         NEW.zip_code:= concat((SUBSTRing(NEW.zip_code, 1, 2))::varchar(2),(SUBSTRING(NEW.zip_code, 3, 1))::varchar(1), (SUBSTRING(NEW.zip_code, 3, 5))::varchar(3));
         return NEW;
    else
            NEW.zip_code := concat((SUBSTRing(NEW.zip_code, 1, 2))::varchar(2),'-' (SUBSTRING(NEW.zip_code, 3, 5))::varchar(3));
            RETURN NEW;
        end if;
        END;
        $$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Please look at `concat((SUBSTRing(NEW.zip_code, 1, 2))::varchar(2),(SUBSTRING(NEW.zip_code, 3, 1))::varchar(1), (SUBSTRING(NEW.zip_code, 3, 5))::varchar(3))`: Why is the length of the last substring 5, not 4 and why make it `varchar(3)`, not  `varchar(4)`? And in the first place, why are you even rip the string apart just to paste it together the way it was? You know that its length is 6 and that it has a '-' at position 3.

Comment: you can use `replace`  instead of `concat and substring`  just repace the `-` with `''` .

Comment: At a second look I see a syntax error at `...,'-' (SUBSTRING(NEW.zip_code, 3, 5))::varchar(3))`. It should be `,'-', (SUBSTRING(NEW.zip_code, 3, 5))::varchar(3))`. I wonder how you could create and use the function. Meaning, `CREATE` should have failed. Are you sure you posted the latest edit of that function?

Comment: There should be something like that:  (SUBSTRING(NEW.zip_code, 4, 6))::varchar(3));. I missed that one. Thanks for help.